# Retrieving the history of keys

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I understand world state always has the latest value of the state. How is it possible to retrieve History of keys ? Is it referring the "ledger" to pull up this information ?

Answer (score 0):

From the chaincode, you can use the `getGetHistoryForKey` and `GetCreator` API to access the history of a specific key. [See here](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim#ChaincodeStub).